# Can non-exported definitions in C++ module interface partitions conflict?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I'm trying to use the latest Clang and C++ modules. The behavior below has me a bit confused. Is it expected, or a bug? I thought because the symbols were static and not exported they would be private to the files and not conflict.

I'm still trying to get a grip on how to use the different module file types (primary interface, implementation, interface partition, internal partition).

Maybe in this case I was trying to use an *interface partition* as if it were an implementation file, when really it should only declare things that I intend to share/export.

#### File *Mod.cc*

```cpp
export module TheMod;
export import :Part1;
export import :Part2;
```

#### File *Part1.cc*

```cpp
export module TheMod:Part1;
static int loog = 1;
... other exported definitions ...
```

#### File *Part2.cc*

```cpp
export module TheMod:Part2;
import :Part1;
static int loog = 2;
... other exported definitions ...
```

Error from Clang:

```
Part2.cc:6:12: error: redefinition of 'loog'
static int loog = 2;
           ^
Part1.cc:4:12: note: previous definition is here
static int loog = 1;
```

Here is a simple build script to reproduce the error with the Clang I have currently. I real life I run these experiments as part of a large CMake project, but this minimal script causes the same error:

#### File *build.sh*

```
CXX="/Dev/llvm-project/build/bin/clang++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -std=c++2b"
set -e
$CXX -fprebuilt-module-path=. -x c++-module Part1.cc --precompile -o TheMod-Part1.pcm
$CXX -fprebuilt-module-path=. -x c++-module Part2.cc --precompile -o TheMod-Part2.pcm
```

The `-isysroot` flag is because I'm on macOS. The `-x c++-module` flags are because I don't like having all these different extensions (and it's what CMake does). You might not need them if you use `.cppm` or something that Clang likes.

Comment: What  clang++ version are you using? I'm getting a whole bunch of errors with clang++ 15.0.7 but not the one you get. Also, how are you trying to compile this?

Comment: Very recent - I pulled from HEAD a few days ago. I left out the CMake setup to simplify the question. Maybe I should add a build shell script or something.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be clearer if you just added the command(s) used to compile it from the command line. You could set it up in a CMake project at https://godbolt.org though. That way you could at least use clang++ 16 or trunk.

Comment: Clang claims only partial implementation of modules. So bugs and other issues are expected. MSVC claims fulls implementation of modules but still has a bunch of bugs.

Comment: If this reproduces on HEAD but not 15.x or 16.x, you should report this as a regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either a Clang bug or a misuse of Clang's implementation of modules.

`static` variables always have internal linkage. And linkage defines from which scopes a name is accessible. Internal linkage means that the name only refers to the declared entity from within the translation unit that declared the name.

Every partition of a module is a module unit, which is a separate translation unit (TU) from every other TU. Therefore, the name `loog` only refers to the `static` variable declared in the `Part1` partition from *within* that partition.

I tried your code in [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), and it compiled fine. I even added an exported function to each partition to print their individual `loog` values, and they worked fine.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will report an bug.

Answer (score 0):

I used your files exactly as you showed them but removed the `... other exported definitions ...` comments.

I added `main.cc`:

```cpp
import TheMod;

int main() {}
```

... and modified the build script like so:

```bash
CXX="clang++ -std=c++2b"
set -e
$CXX -fprebuilt-module-path=. -x c++-module Part1.cc --precompile -o TheMod-Part1.pcm
$CXX -fprebuilt-module-path=. -x c++-module Part2.cc --precompile -o TheMod-Part2.pcm
$CXX -fprebuilt-module-path=. -x c++-module Mod.cc --precompile -o TheMod.pcm
$CXX -fprebuilt-module-path=. TheMod-Part1.pcm TheMod-Part2.pcm TheMod.pcm main.cc -o main
```

This compiled clean using `clang version 15.0.7 (Fedora 15.0.7-1.fc37)`.

I suggest using the latest official release as see how that works out instead of pulling `clang++` HEAD and get potentially unfinished/buggy features.